# Mapbox fit markers with clusters

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to work out how to automatically zoom / fly to a group of markers on a map loaded via a geojson file, but with clustering.

I have my map, markers and clustering working with the [example code from Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/).

However I can't work out how to create an array of coordinates from the geojson source so I can run [fitBounds](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/).

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
// Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v11',
center: [-103.5917, 40.6699],
zoom: 3
});
 
map.on('load', () => {
// Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and
// set the 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will
// add the point_count property to your source data.
map.addSource('earthquakes', {
type: 'geojson',
// Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ earthquakes
// from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
data: 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson',
cluster: true,
clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
});
 
map.addLayer({
id: 'clusters',
type: 'circle',
source: 'earthquakes',
filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
paint: {
// Use step expressions (https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/expressions/#step)
// with three steps to implement three types of circles:
//   * Blue, 20px circles when point count is less than 100
//   * Yellow, 30px circles when point count is between 100 and 750
//   * Pink, 40px circles when point count is greater than or equal to 750
'circle-color': [
'step',
['get', 'point_count'],
'#51bbd6',
100,
'#f1f075',
750,
'#f28cb1'
],
'circle-radius': [
'step',
['get', 'point_count'],
20,
100,
30,
750,
40
]
}
});
 
map.addLayer({
id: 'cluster-count',
type: 'symbol',
source: 'earthquakes',
filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
layout: {
'text-field': ['get', 'point_count_abbreviated'],
'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
'text-size': 12
}
});
 
map.addLayer({
id: 'unclustered-point',
type: 'circle',
source: 'earthquakes',
filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
paint: {
'circle-color': '#11b4da',
'circle-radius': 4,
'circle-stroke-width': 1,
'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
}
});
```

I would imagine this is a fairly common requirement and should really have an example of its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the clusters loaded data on the `'data'` event.
As specified in the [Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map.event:data), it will fire everytime some data loads or changes.

```js
map.on('data', 'clusters', (e) => {
  // e.features = geojson features with type, properties, and geometry, 
  //              in this case each feature is a cluster.

  // Calculate the bounding box for the cluster 
  const bounds = new 
  mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates, 
  e.features[0].geometry.coordinates);

  // Fit the map to the calculated bounds
  map.fitBounds(bounds, { padding: 20 });
  map.setZoom(7);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Mandax but I am having a few problems with this. It no longer allows me to interact with the map (zoom etc), probably something to do with the event constantly being fired. And secondly having the map.setZoom(7) function, doesn't that override fitBounds? Shouldn't fitBounds automatically calculate the zoom and centre point of the map?